# Issue with Spark Window over with Group By

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I want to populate agg over window which with a different grain than select group by.
Using Scala sql.

```
Select c1,c2,c3,max(c4),max(c5),
Max(c4) over (partition by c1,c2,c3),
Avg(c5) over (partition by c1,c2,c3)
From temp_view 
Group by c1,c2,c3
```

Getting **Error** saying :

```
c4 and c5 not being part of Group by or use first().
```

Comment: you do not need to use Group by when you are using partition by..keep it as Select c1,c2,c3,max(c4),max(c5), Max(c4) over (partition by c1,c2,c3), Avg(c5) over (partition by c1,c2,c3) From temp_view

Comment: Thanks @Nikk ... Was trying to understand reason behind thisnot allowing group by... could you explain?

Comment: GroupBy and PartitionBy share the same purpose in few aspects. If you use GroupBy then all aggregation work over these GroupBy columns only. Same thing occur when you use partition by. The only major difference between both is groupBy Reduces the no. of records and In select we need to use only columns which are used in group by But in ParitionBy No. of records will not be reduced. Instead of that it will add one extra column and In select we can use N no. of columns. No restrictions.

Comment: thank you Nikk.. could you answer this question instead of comment ?

Comment: Kim, Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, `GroupBy` and `PartitionBy` share the same purpose in a few aspects. If you use `GroupBy` then all aggregation work over these `GroupBy` columns only. The same thing occurs when you use `partition by`. The only major difference between both is `groupBy` Reduces the no. of records and In select we need to use only columns which are used in group by But in `ParitionBy` Number of records will not be reduced. Instead of that it will add one extra aggregated column and In select we can use N no. of columns.

For your issue, you are using columns c1,c2,c3 in Group By and using Max(c4), AVG(c5) with partition by so it is giving you error.
For you use case, you can use either of below queries:

```
Select c1,c2,c3,max(c4),max(c5)
From temp_view 
Group by c1,c2,c3
```

OR

```
Select c1,c2,c3,
Max(c4) over (partition by c1,c2,c3),
Avg(c5) over (partition by c1,c2,c3)
From temp_view
```

Below is the example which will give you a clear picture,

```
scala> spark.sql("""SELECT * from table""").show()
+---+----------------+-------+------+
| ID|            NAME|COMPANY|SALARY|
+---+----------------+-------+------+
|  1|    Gannon Chang|    ABC|440993|
|  2|   Hashim Morris|    XYZ| 49140|
|  3|       Samson Le|    ABC|413890|
|  4|   Brandon Doyle|    XYZ|384118|
|  5|    Jacob Coffey|    BCD|504819|
|  6|   Dillon Holder|    ABC|734086|
|  7|Salvador Vazquez|    NGO|895082|
|  8|    Paki Simpson|    BCD|305046|
|  9|   Laith Stewart|    ABC|943750|
| 10|  Simon Whitaker|    NGO|561896|
| 11|   Denton Torres|    BCD| 10442|
| 12|Garrison Sellers|    ABC| 53024|
| 13| Theodore Bolton|    TTT|881521|
| 14|   Kamal Roberts|    TTT|817422|
+---+----------------+-------+------+

//You can only use column to select that is in group by
scala> spark.sql("""SELECT COMPANY, max(SALARY) from table group by COMPANY""").show()
+-------+-----------+
|COMPANY|max(SALARY)|
+-------+-----------+
|    NGO|     895082|
|    BCD|     504819|
|    XYZ|     384118|
|    TTT|     881521|
|    ABC|     943750|
+-------+-----------+

//It will give error if you select all column or column other than Group By

scala> spark.sql("""SELECT *, max(SALARY) from table group by COMPANY""").show()
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: expression 'table.`ID`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;;
Aggregate [COMPANY#94], [ID#92, NAME#93, COMPANY#94, SALARY#95L, max(SALARY#95L) AS max(SALARY)#213L]
+- SubqueryAlias table
   +- Relation[ID#92,NAME#93,COMPANY#94,SALARY#95L] parquet

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:41)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.failAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$CheckAnalysis$class$$anonfun$$checkValidAggregateExpression$1(CheckAnalysis.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:220)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:220)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:220)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:641)
  ... 49 elided


//But you can select all columns with partition by
scala> spark.sql("""SELECT *, Max(SALARY) over (PARTITION BY COMPANY) as Max_Salary from table""").show()
+---+----------------+-------+------+----------+
| ID|            NAME|COMPANY|SALARY|Max_Salary|
+---+----------------+-------+------+----------+
|  7|Salvador Vazquez|    NGO|895082|    895082|
| 10|  Simon Whitaker|    NGO|561896|    895082|
|  5|    Jacob Coffey|    BCD|504819|    504819|
|  8|    Paki Simpson|    BCD|305046|    504819|
| 11|   Denton Torres|    BCD| 10442|    504819|
|  2|   Hashim Morris|    XYZ| 49140|    384118|
|  4|   Brandon Doyle|    XYZ|384118|    384118|
| 13| Theodore Bolton|    TTT|881521|    881521|
| 14|   Kamal Roberts|    TTT|817422|    881521|
|  1|    Gannon Chang|    ABC|440993|    943750|
|  3|       Samson Le|    ABC|413890|    943750|
|  6|   Dillon Holder|    ABC|734086|    943750|
|  9|   Laith Stewart|    ABC|943750|    943750|
| 12|Garrison Sellers|    ABC| 53024|    943750|
+---+----------------+-------+------+----------+
```